# What is the relation between (physicists) functional derivatives and Fréchet derivatives

Tags: mathematical-physics, variational-calculus, differentiation, functional-derivatives

I´m wondering how can one get to the definition of Functional Derivative found on most Quantum Field Theory books:

$$\frac{\delta F[f(x)]}{\delta f(y) } = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{F[f(x)+\epsilon \delta(x-y)]-F[f(x)]}{\epsilon}$$

from the definitions of Functional Derivatives used by mathematicians (I´ve seen many claims that it is, in effect, the Fréchet derivative, but no proofs). The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) says it´s just a matter of using the delta function as “test function” but then goes on to say that it is nonsense.

Where does this $\delta(x-y)$ comes from?

Comment: Waiting for an actual answer, but note that Dirac delta comes from the fact that $F[x]$ is the functional applied to the function $x$ and the functional derivative is with respect to the function $y$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever I have troubles with functional derivative things, I just do the replacement of a continuous variable $x$ into a discrete index $i$. If I'm not mistaken this is what they call a "[DeWitt notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation)".

The hand waiving idea is that you can think of a functional $F[f(x)]$ as of a "ordinary function" of many variables $F(f_{-N},\cdots,f_0,f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_N) = F(\vec{f})$ with $N$ going to "continuous infinity".

In that language your functional derivative transforms into partial derivative over one of the variables:
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)} \to \frac{\partial F}{\partial f_i}$$
And the delta-function is just an ordinary Kronecker delta:
$$\delta(x-y) \to \delta_{ij}$$

So, gathering this up we for your expression:
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)} = \lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\frac{F[f(x)+\epsilon\delta(x-y)]-F[f(x)]}{\epsilon} \to$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial f_j} = \lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\frac{F[f_i+\epsilon\delta_{ij}]-F[f_i]}{\epsilon} $$
Which is, to my taste, a bit redundant. But true.

Comment: Don't you mean to take $\epsilon\to 0$ not $\epsilon\to\infty$?  Also note that strictly speaking, $F[f(x)]$ is typically a slight (but admittedly common) abuse of notation.  $F$ is supposed to eat functions and spit out numbers, but $f(x)$ is a number, while $f$ is a function.  I find it preferable to write $F[f]$ to avoid confusion.  In this case, one would then write $\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)}[f] = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{F[f+\epsilon\delta_x] - F[f]}{\epsilon}$, where $\delta_x$ is the delta impulse centered at $x$.

Answer (score 7):

This is a formal notation for the following general thing:

$$F(f+\delta f) = F(f) + \int A(x) \delta f(x) $$

Where $\delta f$ is the infinitesimal change in f, and it is a smooth test function, and then on the right hand side, $A(x)$ is just a linear operator on the space of functions. The notation for the $A(x)$ is then

$$ A(x) = {\delta F\over \delta f(x)}$$

Because if you *formally* substitude $\delta f(x) = \delta(x-y)$, you find $A(y)$ as the value of the integral. This is just a notational trick--- $\delta f$ is an everywhere small variation, which is impossible if it is infinite at one point. Another way of saying this is that the point-delta-function limit has to be taken after the small epsilon limit in the definition you give, so that the variation becomes small before it becomes infinitely concentrated.

Answer (score 5):

The physicist's derivative notation denotes the components of a Frechet derivative in the direction of the delta-function supported at $y$.

This is one of those places where the habit of denoting the function $f$ by its value $f(x)$ gets confusing.  It's somewhat clearer if you write $\delta_y$ for the delta function at $y$, and

$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta (\delta_y)}[f] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} ( F[f + \epsilon \delta_y] - F[f]).
$$

Obviously, the delta function isn't actually a function.  But this use of it makes exactly as much sense as the position basis (and the latter can be made perfectly rigorous using rigged Hilbert  spaces).

Comment: That´s exactly my problem with this definition (Dirac delta subtleties apart). It seems your are defining the partial derivative in the specific direction of $\delta_y$, but this very definition is used everywhere as the partial derivative in any direction (are they all the same?).

Another way of expressing my problem: is the first equality below valid? Why? (I tried to follow your notation, $f_y$ means f calculated at point $y$):

$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta (f_y)}[f] =  \frac{\delta F}{\delta (\delta_y)}[f] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} ( F[f + \epsilon \delta_y] - F[f]).
$$

Comment: The definition works for any function.  You define the derivative of $F$ at $f$ in the direction of $f+g$ for any function $g$ to be $\frac{\delta F}{\delta g} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} (F[f+\epsilon g] - F[f])$.  This is just like in multivariable calculus; it tells you how $F$ changes to first order if you move from $f$ towards $f+g$.  

The special degenerate case $g = \delta_y$ tells you how $F$ changes if you modify $f$ only by changing its value at $y$.  This is the source of the crazy physics notation.

Comment: Also, please don't use the notation $f_y$ for $f(y)$; this does not make the world a better place.  $f(y)$ is the value of a function.  $\delta_y$ (which seems to have inspired you) is a distribution which is non-zero only at $y$.  

If it helps, you can imagine that when physicists write $f(y)$ in the denominator of a functional derivative, they are actually taking the derivative along the "coordinate" $f \mapsto f(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let the definition of the functional derivative be

$$
\int \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)} \phi(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{F[\rho + \epsilon \phi] - F[\rho]}{\epsilon}
$$

Choose

$$ \phi(x) = \delta(x-y) $$

And complete the integration on the left-hand side

$$ \int \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)}\delta(x-y) dx = \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(y)} = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{F[\rho + \epsilon \delta(x-y)] - F[\rho]}{\epsilon} $$

Let a physicist choose a function in an integrand, and he'll choose a delta function every time.