# How to show functional derivative as a limit of ordinary derivative?

Tags: differentiation, calculus, discrete, functional-derivatives

[image: I found this footnote in the appendix (on path integral page 333) of j.polchinsky’s string theory book.can you explain this?]

I found this footnote in the appendix (on path integral page 333) of J. Polchinski’s string theory book. can you explain this?

Comment: Ultimately this might be better suited to mathematics, you might find a more convincing argument from a mathematical point of view instead.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/467771/different-definitions-of-functional-derivative) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30338/what-is-the-relation-between-physicists-functional-derivatives-and-fréchet-der).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Definition),
$$
 \delta F[q;\phi]= \int \!\! dt~\frac{\delta F}{\delta q(t)} \phi(t)   
= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{F[q+\varepsilon \phi]-F[q]}{\varepsilon}  
= \left [ \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}F[q+\varepsilon \phi]\right ]_{\varepsilon=0},
 $$
where $\phi (t)$ specifies the direction of the functional derivative in $\delta q(t)$.

Now take a special $F[q]\equiv \int \!\! d\tau ~~\delta(\tau-t') q(\tau)=q(t')$,
so
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta q(t)}= \delta(t-t').
$$

It's easiest if you think of *t* as the continuum limit of a discrete integer index *i*,  so a vector $q_i \to q(t)$. Note that the vector calculus gradient, $\partial q_i/\partial q_j = \delta_{ij} $ tends to the above expression.

Then, for example, the gradient of a scalar function goes to a vector,
$$
\frac{\partial (q_jq_j)}{\partial q_i} =2q_i ~~~\to ~~~\frac{\delta \int\!\!dt' ~q(t')q(t') }{\delta q(t)}= 2q(t).
$$